# Pyhook wait until keyup

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pyhook

I found this code on here somewhere and I would like to make it to stop printing until the key pressed is up again. I made it wait for a different key in order to print again but then if I had to type something like "Google" it would only print something for one "O" when I want it to print for both. I'm trying 2 days now to do it with no success. Any help would be appreciated instead of the classic 2-3 dislikes I'm getting in this site.

```
from random import *
from pyHook import HookManager
from win32gui import PumpMessages, PostQuitMessage

class Keystroke_Watcher(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.on_keyboard_down
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()



    def on_keyboard_up(self, event):
        return False


    def on_keyboard_down(self, event):
        space = False
        try:
            if event.KeyID  == 32:
                print('space')
                space = True
            x = randint(0, 1)
            if space == False:
                if x == 0:
                    print(x)
                else:
                    print(x)
        finally:
            return True



    def shutdown(self):
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()





watcher = Keystroke_Watcher()
```